# Form in Jquery Mobile pop-up disappears when using as standalone app for iPad

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a simple form in a pop-up (user registration). It works fine in mobile safari, but when U put a shortcut on the homescreen (with the web-app capable meta tag), the pop-up disappears when selecting an input field. Is there someway to fix this? Some meta tag maybe?

Some sample code:

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <h1>Page</h1>
    <a href="#nav-panel" data-icon="bars" class="ui-btn-left">Menu</a>
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-mini ui-btn-right">
        <a href="#popupCreateUser" data-rel="popup"  data-icon="plus" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-plus" data-position-to="window">Create user</a> <!-- this opens the popup -->
    </div>
    </div>

<div data-role="content">
<ul data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true" data-filter="true" data-inset="true" id="userListView">

</ul>
</div>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupCreateUser" data-overlay-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all" style="width:400px;">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
    <h1>Gebruiker toevoegen</h1>
    </div>
    <form method="post" id="createUser" action="users-actions.php">
        <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="add" />
            <label for="user" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Gebruikersnaam:</label>
            <input type="text" name="user" id="user" value="" placeholder="gebruikersnaam" data-theme="a" minlength="2">
            <button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check">Aanmaken</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do you call the popup? is it placed inside page div?

Comment: Yes, both the popup and the link that opens the popup are placed inside the page div, I'll update my question with some sample code.